# org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException by netty HTTP handler

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, timeoutexception

I am running tests using selenium webdriver. But with 111 chrome update, had to add "--remote-allow-origins=*" argument to make webdriver work. Then started getting following exception at random elements(findElement)/commands(sendKeys, switchTo)

```
`org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
Build info: version: '4.6.0', revision: '79f1c02ae20'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [93f8e26807f72a1db301042970c404c3, clickElement {id=99af3643-8e51-46fd-849a-a6968fb6916a}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 111.0.5563.65, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 111.0.5563.64 (c710e93d5b63..., userDataDir: C:\Users\kalkidna\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:49445}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:49445/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 111.0.5563.65, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Element: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (93f8e26807f72a1db301042970c404c3)] -> id: submitbutton]
Session ID: 93f8e26807f72a1db301042970c404c3
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:65)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.execute(NettyHttpHandler.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.execute(NettyClient.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:541)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:257)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:78)
    at com.classes.SCLFiles.SCLFileLoading.sclFileLoad(SCLFileLoading.java:722)
    at com.classes.SCLFiles.SCLFileLoading.uploadFileWithGooseAndSampledValues(SCLFileLoading.java:1160)
    at com.testcases.SCLFiles.SCLFileLoadingTest.fileUploadWithGooseAndSVMessagesTest(SCLFileLoadingTest.java:369)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1950)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2085)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyResponseFuture.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:59)
    ... 43 more`
```

I am using the following dependencies

```
`<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-http-jdk-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-testng-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.55</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-appengine</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>`
```

also added "no-sandbox" argument to chromeoptions as well.